# Switch multiple contacts in parallel from a single 24V DDC output

Tags: digital-logic, signal, switching

I have a DDC (direct digital control) with a 24V digital output and I need to control around 100 external circuits, each having their own input.

The switching distance between DDC and remote panel will be anywhere from 25 meters to 100 meters, they would share the same building ground.

There are **two** types of output available on the DDC (and ideally would like to use both types to increase the utilization, ratings below are per output):

1. Digital output dry contact (relay contact, SPST NO, 48VA at 24VAC)- pilot drive @ 24VDC 0.5A, or direct drive @ 24VDC 0.5A.
2. Universal output configured as digital output. Open Collector Output, Max Sinking Current Rating: 200mA @ 24VDC.

I would like to connect them in parallel and switch all at the same time (near, timing isn't key).

I don't want to have to provide 100 DDC I/O to do this, and would like to do it via as few as possible outputs (ideally one DDC output to 100 external circuits) - even if one DDC output could control 10 external dry contact circuits that is ok.

Questions please:

1. Is the switching of multiple external circuits in parallel possible in this manner (intermediate higher power relay is OK), if so what calculations would need to be looked at to ensure we are well within head room of what current the DDC can source (if any is required)?
2. This input type of the remote systems can be specified at this time as the remote devices are yet to be built, if it is advantageous to use opto-isolated inputs then we can specify this.
3. The [manual states on page 11](http://www.syxthsense.com/product/manuals/easyio-fg-20.pdf) of the digital output wiring connection `It does not output voltage or current. It is a dry relay contact` - is it right to say that the meaning 'dry' for the digital output (as opposed to the universal output which is open collector) is that it is not sourcing its own current and we need to provide the 24V externally, and it is just the switch that is closed in the output within the DDC electronics? What is the difference in meaning between pilot drive and direct drive?
4. I see one question in comments as `what voltage is present on the dry contact inputs, how much current flows when you complete the circuit?` I guess the current depends on the input if it is opto-isolated or a dry contact relay (we are free to specify) - any benchmark current ratings between opto-isolators and dry contact current required @ 24V?

Comment: What does DDC mean?

Comment: @Bruce: I found this: "Even though direct digital control (DDC) is a majorpart of the HVAC industry, it remains surrounded by a cloud of mystery." Since it's surrounded by a cloud of mystery we may never understand. [More](https://dms.hvacpartners.com/docs/1001/public/0c/wp010.pdf).

Comment: Do you mean, that each of these 100 circuits has its own relay at the input? This will be a lot of current to drive for a digital output!

Comment: what voltage is present on the dry contact inputs, how much current flows when you complete the circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question properly requires an understanding of the output characteristics of the outputs and inputs. Of particular importance would be the understanding of:

- Outputs: relay or transistor? If transistor:

  - Are they opto-isolated from the controller?
  - Do they share a common with other outputs?
  - What is the output rating?
- Inputs:

  - Are they opto-isolated from the controller?
  - Do they share a common with other inputs?
  - Do they share a common ground or V+ with other inputs?
  - How far apart are they and is there a risk of different earth / ground potentials?
  - What is the input current requirement?

If grounding and commons are not a problem it's just a matter of calculating how many inputs can be driven by the output contact with sufficient reliability derating.

Comment: Thanks, have updated my question with more info on the above, we are free to define the interface of the remote input.

Answer (score 2):

for 100 dry-contact signals buy 25  four-pole relays. (four pole seems to be the best price point)

There should be a way to command the 25 relays from a single output.

Perhaps wire the coils in parallel and use another higher current relay to switch the current that runs these.